# vim clang complete

Tags: vim, autocomplete, clang

I found a modern plugin for vim completion, but there is no information (even in plugin vim help) how to use it. Can somebody explain me what I need to use it and how to configure vim? Any tricks and tips are welcome.
[clang complete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in [the plugin itself](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/blob/master/plugin/clang_complete.vim#L84): `<C-x><C-u>` to trigger omni-completion manually and it seems to be triggered after hitting `.:>`.

Comment: How do I need to attach clang tool to it?

Comment: Once you have installed the plugin it should work out of the box in INSERT mode.

Comment: Just like any autocomplete/omni complete based plugin, clang_compelte is much easier to work with when using SuperTab. SuperTab automatically lets you just use tab, even though you have multiple completion plugins like SnipMate and clang_complete.

Answer (score 0):

clang_complete just expects clang to be installed on your system. Install a recent version, or compile it from svn and that's it. If you want to use the libclang option which is much faster, you will need python and VIM with python enabled.